# Jquery loop para ler 3 objetos e criar 3 dataPoints para charts canvas

Tags: jquery, canvas

Estou tentando realizar o *loop* no retorno desta solicitação *AJAX*. No primeiro evento `success`, eu realizo uma segunda chamada *AJAX* que irá retornar — neste caso — 3 objetos *JSON*.

A minha duvida é como criar, no segundo evento `success`, 3 *dataPoints* que irão gerar e popular 3 gráficos feitos em canvas?

**Código jQuery:**

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'dadosPS.php?ps=getGerencialPergunta&pesquisa='+slct_ps+'&datainicio='+dtin+'&datafim='+dtf,
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function () {

            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              var dataPoints = [];
              var dataPoints2 = [];
              var tt = 0;
              var count = $.map(data.data, function(n, i) { return i; }).length;//conta qtd de perguntas

              $.each(data.data, function (key, val) {
               id = val.id;
               dataPoints.push({y:parseInt(val.qtd),label:val.pergunta});
                    if(val.nr_pergunta == '1'){
                       tt = val.qtd++;
                    }
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'get',
                            url: 'dadosPS.php?ps=getGerencialResposta&id='+id+'&pesquisa='+slct_ps+'&datainicio='+dtin+'&datafim='+dtf,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            async: false,
                            beforeSend: function () {

                            },
                            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                             console.log(data);                      
                            },
                            complete: function () {

                            },
                            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            }
                        });  



              });

               //grafico das perguntas
                    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("teste0", {
                    //colorSet:  "customColorSet1",
                    title: {
                        text: tt,
                          //horizontalAlign: "left"
                          verticalAlign: "center",
                          dockInsidePlotArea: true
                    },
                    animationEnabled: true,
                    exportEnabled: true,
                legend: {
                maxWidth: 350,
                itemWidth: 120
            },
                    data: [{
                            type: "doughnut",
                            indexLabel: "{label} {y}",
                            //startAngle: 240,
                            //showInLegend: true,
                //legendText: "{label}",
                            dataPoints: dataPoints
                        }]
                });
                chart.render();




            },
            complete: function () {

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
       });
```

**Retorno do segundo `success`**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: explique um pouco melhor por favor, vc já faz a criação de datapoints no primeiro call, por que não replica a estratégia no segundo call?

Comment: Então no primeiro eu gero um dado e no código tem um id que leio no each e passo esse id para o segundo ajax....neste caso sao tres ids e no retorno do segundo ajax preciso criar os 3 graficos mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Não analisei os pormenores, mas só em ver um Ajax sendo chamado dentro de um loop each já me dá calafrios. Imagine chamar um Ajax atrás do outro sem fazer "fila"... não sei se isso dá certo.

Comment: Claro que nao é a melhor forma mas se tiver outra maneira , por favor  pode me dar uma dica :)